# TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a toggle between 3 components and i keep getting this error.(TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null). I there state keep updating but the does not pick the value from the switch case

```
class DevStageToggle extends React.Component {
  state = { show: 1 };

  onSubmitContinue = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.onShowDev();
  };

  onShowDev = () => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({ show: show + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onSubmitContinue}>changes</button>
        <br />
        {this.state.show && <Options show={this.state.show} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Options extends React.Component {
  render() {
    switch (this.state.show) {
      case 1:
        return <div>Please select Development Stage</div>;
      case 2:
        return <div>Idea stage</div>;
      case 3:
        return <div>Early Stage</div>;
      case 4:
        return <div>Growth Stage</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default DevStageToggle;
```

Comment: You have to change `this.state.show` in Options component to `this.props.show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the switch, instead of `this.state.show` it should be `this.props.show`

```
class Options extends React.Component {
  render() { // getting show from props
    switch (this.props.show) {
      case 1:
        return <div>Please select Development Stage</div>;
      case 2:
        return <div>Idea stage</div>;
      case 3:
        return <div>Early Stage</div>;
      case 4:
        return <div>Growth Stage</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

When you render a component and pass a prop to it

```
// rendering component and passing show prop to it
<Options show={this.state.show} />
```

The prop value will come in `this.props` not in `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

> It should be `switch (this.props.show)`.

```
class DevStageToggle extends React.Component {
  state = { show: 1 };

  onSubmitContinue = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.onShowDev();
  };

  onShowDev = () => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({ show: show + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onSubmitContinue}>changes</button>
        <br />
        {this.state.show && <Options show={this.state.show} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Options extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { show } = this.props;

    switch (show) {
      case 1:
        return <div>Please select Development Stage</div>;
      case 2:
        return <div>Idea stage</div>;
      case 3:
        return <div>Early Stage</div>;
      case 4:
        return <div>Growth Stage</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default DevStageToggle;
```